# Get syntax from Google Spreadsheet cell (or a Google doc) into a Google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I would like to be able to get some code from either a cell or a google doc into a google script. 
So is it possible to not only retrieve some value, but also retrieve some code from a cell en run it in google script?

Answer (score 0):

```
function test_eval()
{
  var str = 'var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();\n';
  eval(str);

  Logger.log(sheet.getName());

}
```

Please see info here:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot a of sense. Is this also valid for getting code from a google doc ("Word" file)?

Comment: It works in `google-apps-script`, my code from sample may be converted to doc, but with document's classes: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/